# Command which shows the number of people having a role when the role name is typed in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I already made a dump command showing all people having a role here is the code:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content == `+dump admin`) {
        const ListEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Users with the admin role:')
            .setDescription(message.guild.roles.cache.get('741231292544188439').members.map(m=>m.user.tag).join('\n'));
        message.channel.send(ListEmbed);                    
    }
});
```

However this only shows for the Admin Role. Is there anyway possible it shows for the role mentioned or the role name. For example:
If the command is `+dump Owner` it shows people having that role or if `+dump @Co-Owner` it shows all people having that role. Meaning if command is `+dump ${role}` It shows all people having that role. Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `args` variable to dynamically check what role is sent in the command using [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and the [`ES6` Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Here's a command snippet demonstration:

```js
const content = '+role Trial Moderator'

// slice(1) will slice the prefix off the beginning of the command
// split(/ +/) will split the content by every space and return an array
// we can then use array destructering and the spread operator to define both command and args
const [command, ...args] = content.slice(1).toLowerCase().split(/ +/);

console.log(command);
console.log(args);

// you could use this in a command handler:

if (command === 'something') {
  // something function here
} else if (command === 'role') {
  // we can also use the `args` variable to dynamically check message values
  console.log(args.join(' '))
}
```

---

Now that you have the name, you can use [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) to get the actual role object.

```js
if (command === 'role') {
 // find a role by the same name
 const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
  (role) => role.name.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ')
 );
 if (!role)
  return message.channel.send(
   `Could not find a role by the name \`${args.join(' ')}\``
  );

 // make and send the embed dynamically
 const ListEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Users with the \`${role.name}\` role:`)
  .setDescription(role.members.map((m) => m.user.tag).join('\n'));
 message.channel.send(ListEmbed);
}
```

Comment: I still get a error:


 `const role = client.roles.cache.find(
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`

Comment: Ah, that's my fault. Replace `client` with `message.guild`

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but I'm a bit new to coding. How can I define args here. Once again sorry to disturb you

Comment: Use the code from the code snippet in my answer. Just replace `content` with `message.content`